# Free field realisation for Vertex Operators

Tags: operators, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, ghosts

I wanted to know if for a generic CFT (in weak coupling limit) there exists free field realisation of the vertex operators. This seems like it should exist but I want to know a generic algorithm to find it.

My main motivation is to understand the vertex operators in bosonic $\beta-\gamma$ systems. The action for such a system is
$$S = \int \beta \bar{\partial}\gamma$$
where the fields have conformal weight $\lambda$ and $(1-\lambda)$ respectively. I want to define vertex operators in this theory and write them in terms of the above fields.

Comment: I think the question in your first paragraph is a very deep and interesting one. Just a brief comment on it: The answer is no, there are CFTs that does not have a weakly coupled limit, the (2,0) theory in six dimensions is an example; the existence of weakly coupled or 'classical' limits is important, because vertex operators can be seen as pertubative states.  Even in the realm of 2d CFTs there are theories that are strongly coupled at some point in its parameter space.  Maybe the question of yours should be sharpened to ask for the free field realization of weakly coupled 2d CFTs.

Comment: Yes. The context of this question is that assuming you have a Lagrangian for your CFT and hence an idea of the free field content of the theory, can you write an expression for Vertex operators.

Comment: You are asking about conformal manifolds in two dimensions that contain a free point. If you find a free field realization that continues to work at a finite distance away from that free point, there's no way the approach is going to suddenly know when that finite distance stops being something that humans would call "small".